# Error: Attribute is missing android namespace prefix

Tags: android, xml, styles

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <style name="spinner_style">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownWidth">533dp</item>
        <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/bluetooth</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownHeight">70dp</item>
        <item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">true</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

All I am trying to do is custom style my android spinner. So I made a style file, but no matter what I do, there is red underlining everywhere with the error stated above.

Comment: Is this in a layout file or a resource file?

Comment: I'm not aware that `<merge>` works for style resources.

Comment: styles.xml under the layout folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Styles.xml should be in values folder. Also I wouldn't use merge here, not sure if it makes it crash or not though. I am using resources instead.